# How to show line number of exception throw in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: exception, intellij-idea, intellij-13

How do I show a line number that says where an exception was thrown on runtime?  Currently the IDE only displays the exception name, and no stack trace of any kind, making it very difficult to debug. I have searched the IntelliJ docs and haven't been able to find a simple answer (I don't want to have to use breakpoints and debugging commands).

Comment: what do you mean it displays the exception name? Can you explain a bit what kind of application do you have? How do you handle exceptions? Do you handle them?

Comment: It may the issue with your logger configuration.

Comment: Can you give us some sample code that throws an exception to look at?

Answer (score 0):

It is basic Java stuff. You must print the stacktrace in your application to see line numbers, not just the exception itself which produces #toString() output.